# Как запустить python скрипт через ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, centos

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить python скрипт, который расположен на сервере, через ssh соединение. У меня нет прав администратора. Все способы, которые были в интернете, пробовал, но ничего не получалось. На сервере CentOS 8 Stream.

Comment: Права на запуск скрипта есть? Скрипт выполняемый?

Comment: Да просто `python путь/к/скрипту.py` да и всё, не? Даже права на запуск не нужны

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваши попытки. Без них вообще непонятно что вы называете ssh соединением.

Comment: ssh user@machine /usr/bin/python3.11 < script.py - arg1 arg2   # пробовали?

Comment: cat hello.py | ssh user@192.168.1.101 python -  # вариант со своим скриптом   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499074/run-local-python-script-on-remote-server